# select box jquery is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

I can not get rid of this error, and its to the point where i just started adding sources to the header hoping something would work. What could possibly be causing these errors? this is a form helper in rails.

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.self-3d0dca634dc5f4aee8c2dddef05674d9a674214500fd7e89959dc9e7251bb717.js:18
    at select2.self-3d0dca634dc5f4aee8c2dddef05674d9a674214500fd7e89959dc9e7251bb717.js:20
reports.self-125a9126dcda5f55eea80b80380e4bf42b79fb01ceba6fbb8c52674b3952fca7.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at reports.self-125a9126dcda5f55eea80b80380e4bf42b79fb01ceba6fbb8c52674b3952fca7.js:2
    at reports.self-125a9126dcda5f55eea80b80380e4bf42b79fb01ceba6fbb8c52674b3952fca7.js:4
reports:59 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
application.self-a24973bbb6a25a64ef1e551cdacacf83cdc7ddd8e2ea49e5c4df1e07a115c569.js?body=1:24 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (application.self-a24973bbb6a25a64ef1e551cdacacf83cdc7ddd8e2ea49e5c4df1e07a115c569.js?body=1:24)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
    at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3583)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3618)

```
<header>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</header>

<h1>Partner Scorecard Generator</h1>


    <%= form_for(:report)  do |f| -%>

    <p>
    <%=f.label "Run date" %><br>
    <%=f.date_field :run_date %><br>
    </p>




    <p>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("setting up select 2");
        $("#selecttwo").select2({
            placeholder: "Select your Partners",
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://services.dwmholdings.com/order.svcs/api/partners',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                processResults: function p(data){
                    console.log(processresults())
                    var mapped = $.map(data, funtion (obj){
                        obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
                        obj.id = obj.id || obj.salesId;
                        console.log(mapped);
                        return obj;



                    })
                    return {
                        results: mapped
                    }

                }


            }
            });
        });
    console.log("hello")
    </script>



    <%= select_tag :sales_ids %>


    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label "Yes send Email" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :send_email, "True" %><br>
    <%= f.label "Do not Email" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :send_email, "False" %>

    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label "recipients" %>
    <%= f.email_field(:recipients) %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label "bcc" %>
    <%= f.email_field(:bcc)%>
    </p>



    <p>
    <%= f.radio_button :Send_Email, "True" %>
    <%= f.label :Debug, "Debug on" %><br>
    <%= f.radio_button :Send_Email, "False" %>
    <%= f.label :Debug, "Debug off" %>
    </p>


    <p>
    <%=f.submit %>
    </p>



<!-- :class => "selecttwo",
        :multiple=>true, 
        :size =>20,
        :id => "selecttwo" -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: please help me i have been working on this for two weeks -_-

Answer (score 1):

You are loading jquery.min.js as well as jquery.js. Try removing one of those two. This error occurs if sister or same javascripts are getting loaded on same page.

Comment: Please vote my ans if your issue is solved due to my ans. Thanks.

Comment: @perry Please vote my ans if your issue is solved due to my ans. Thanks.

Comment: @swag 15 reputation points are needed to be able to upvote, so perry can't.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#foo").select2()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="foo"></div>
```

Trying using `https` instead of `http` in your script `src`.  Seems to work in this simplified example.

Comment: negative, and I added to them all

Comment: i even switched too a couple different cdns this is what is looks like now, no change.

<script src=“https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js“></script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />